# How make big real time app use socket.io or lightstreamer and scale horizontal

Tags: node.js, socket.io, load-balancing

I have got some questions with real time app.
I am making a real time app at this time. I used socket.io,mongodb and nodejs. This app works nice in prototype but what will happen when the number of users increases?
I want to grow horizontal scale.

e.g I have got two server (server A, server B)

client A connect server A

Client B connect server B

How can Client A send message Client B? It has been confusing me with different servers
I found the use redis for this. Is there a possibility that redis-server enough?

As a result, what should I use and which tech(redis,lightstreamer,jabber, socket.io,nginx)?

Comment: There is nothing 'real-time' about this question. Don't tag indiscriminately, and don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send directly a message from A to B because they arn't connected to the same server.

The solution to this is to enable communication between the two node server.

You mentionned redis so if you go that route you can have a central redis server that has two lists (on for each server). When client A want to join client B, he send to server A his message. Server A will not find client B in his local sockets and will push to redis the message. Soon or later, server B will collect his pending messages from redis and dispatch them to client B.

It's a basic implementation that you can change to fit your needs. You can have for example a single list of messages per server, but also why not a list per user (and the server which has this

Also as a side note, any central data store such as a database server (mongo? MySQL?) can do the same as redis. It all comes down to what you allready have, what you can have and what type of persistence you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said, I thought cluster communication. I can make socket server for cluster servers but this is exhaust for network.  How it is made in large projects (whatsapp, facebook)?